# Flutter : How to make button like this

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to make button like this
[image]

The background is of different colors and shapes
Text and icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete code for making one of the buttons. you can play with bordet radius to build other buttons as well.

`enter code here`  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Overlay overlay = const Overlay();

  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '3D Button',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: colors[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text("3D Button"),
        ),
      ),
      // body: const ClickyButtonPage(),
      body: Center(child: const Custom3DButton()),
    );
  }
}

    const MaterialColor colors = Colors.blue;
    const MaterialColor colors2 = Colors.grey;
    
    class Custom3DButton extends StatelessWidget {
      const Custom3DButton({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double _width = 220;
        double _height = 65;
        double _sideWidth = 180;
        var _borderRadius = const Radius.circular(50);
    
        return Container(
          width: _width,
          height: 70.0,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(_borderRadius),
                    color: colors[800],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: _sideWidth * 5 / 6,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: _borderRadius, topLeft: _borderRadius),
                    color: colors2[400],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: _width,
                height: _height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(_borderRadius),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: _sideWidth,
                  height: _height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(_borderRadius),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.menu_rounded,
                          size: 34,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'SETTING',
                          style: TextStyle(color: colors[600], fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is the screen shot for this example;[image]